# Replace n number of rows with condition in R?

Tags: r

I have a df :

```
number=c(3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,4,4)
data.frame(number)
```

but with thousands of rows.

How can i replace `n` number of rows out of way more and turn 3 into 1 for example.

If you can explain the logic too would be great.

No special requirements just replace a certain amount of 3 into 1. Not all.

Either randomly or the first n numbers.

Comment: Could you explain your requirements in a bit more detail. Do you want a run-length encoding of your `number` column?

Comment: What do you mean? if its ok to choose randomly the numbers for replacement?

Comment: are you looking for something like `df$V1[df$V1 == 3] <- 1`?

Comment: No this is just replacing the 3 with 1. i said certain amount of 3s

Comment: So these `n` instances can be chosen in whatever way? E.g., the first `n`, random `n`...

Comment: Let's say your data frame is called `df` and you want to replace `n = 4` 3s to 1s. Is this what you want? `threes = which(df$number == 3)
n = 4
df$number[threes[1:n]] <- 1`.
`n` can be random if you use `sample`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two versions for you. The first assumes you randomly want to convert `n` rows from 3 to 1. The second assumes that you want to choose the first `n` rows from 3 to 1.

To randomly select `n` of the rows where the value is currently 3, and then convert to 1:

```
> number=c(3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,4,4)
> 
> 
> # to randomly change n rows (assume here that n = 4)
> set.seed(1)
> df <- data.frame(v1 = number)
> df$v1[sample(which(df$v1 == 3), 4)] <- 1
> df
   v1
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   3
6   1
7   1
8   1
9   1
10  4
11  4
12  4
13  4
14  4
15  4
```

To change to the first `n` rows (assume again that n = 4):

```
> df <- data.frame(v1 = number)
> df$v1[which(df$v1 == 3)[1:4]] <- 1
> df
   v1
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   3
6   1
7   1
8   1
9   1
10  4
11  4
12  4
13  4
14  4
15  4
```

**Since you wanted the logic for how this works:**

Both answers rely on the `which()` command. Which will give you the location where a vector is `TRUE`, so when we do `which(df$v1 == 3)` this is going to give us the location of all the rows where the `df$v1` is `3`:

```
> df$v1 == 3
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> which(df$v1 == 3)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

We then simply specify that we want to reassign `df$v1` at those positions to 1. However, since you wanted to specify how many rows to do this for, we subset the result of our `which()` vector by using `[1:n]` to select the first n results, or `sample(x, n)` to randomly select n results.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to select `n` appearances of some value in a data.frame column.

For that you can sample, with or without replacement, all the values that match your requirements.

Below I show how to do that for 3 instances of 3's

```
number =c (3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,4,4)
foo = data.frame(number)

indexes = sample(which(foo$number == 3), size = 3, replace = F)
foo$number[indexes] = 'your value'
```